# What is the correct way to handle a null response from an asynchronous function?

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I am working on an Azure function that communicates with my table and updates data in the table. I recently discovered that the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` package only has Async functions now, and I am unfamiliar with those.

In my function I'm using for testing, I want to return true if the row exists, false if it doesn't. It works if the row exists, but the program hangs (because it's waiting for a response) if the row does not exist.

Can anyone help me?

Here is my code:

```
public static bool rowExists(CloudTable table, string city, string state)
{
    TableOperation tOP = TableOperation.Retrieve<SickCity>(city, state);
    Task<TableResult> result = table.ExecuteAsync(tOP);
    if (result == null)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Edit:

Here is where I'm calling rowExists

```
log.Info($"Does the row \"New York, NY\" exist? {rowExists(sickTable, "New York", "NY")}");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't getting the result you expect because your code isn't waiting for the asynchronous request to finish. You need to change your function a bit to properly call `ExecuteAsync`:

```
public static async Task<bool> rowExists(CloudTable table, string city, string state)
{
    TableOperation tOP = TableOperation.Retrieve<SickCity>(city, state);
    var result = await table.ExecuteAsync(tOP);

    if (result == null)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

`ExecuteAsync` returns a `Task`, which won't contain an actual result until some time in the future (when the asynchronous operation completes). The `await` keyword will cause your code to "pause" on that line and wait for the `ExecuteAsync` task to contain an actual value. Then your logic can continue.

Note that the method signature changed: it's now `async Task<bool> rowExists`. Your method now returns a `Task` as well, which means that the code that calls *this* method must also use `await`. This is a common pattern for dealing with async operations like database and network calls.

If this looks weird, you can read more about the async/await pattern here:

- [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) in the C# docs
- [Async and await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on Stephen Cleary's blog

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I'm not familiar at all with asynchronous programming.

Comment: @AndrewBuikema No problem! It takes a bit to wrap your head around at first. I added some links at the bottom of my answer to some good reading on async in C#.

Comment: @AndrewBuikema Welcome to Stack Overflow btw! If my answer solved your problem, feel free to click the checkmark to mark it as the accepted answer. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah I was going to but SO makes me wait for 10 minutes before I can accept an answer. Thanks again!